# After deployed to azure linux app service alignment issue in pdf generation?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, pdf-generation, azure-webapps

net core application with DOCX file to PDF generation using sautinsoft.document package.In local the pdf conversion and alignment was perfect. but deployed to azure linux app service, pdf conversion is working fine but we facing alignment issue. we try to open the both pdf, some fonts are missing in the deployed pdf. if any possible to solve this issue. i have tired multiple option but seems nothing is working for me.

please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I understand from the issue description PDF generation is not working as expected on Azure WebApp; facing alignment and font issues.

All Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. There are limitations - Please check this [Azure App Service Sandbox wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox/ce771ed077ecc17fac1ec4306370b4a249680cc1#general-sandbox-restrictions) for more info:

The following PDF generators are supported:

- SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher
- EVOPDF Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or
  higher.
- Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or
  higher.
- NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan
  Basic or higher

Known issue for all PDF generators based on wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs: custom fonts are not rendered (system-installed font is used instead) because of sandbox GDI API limitations that present even in VM-based Azure Apps plans (Basic or higher).

You may try one of the supported framework or try this via a [App Service custom   container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux).

Reference: Checkout [Unsupported frameworks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox/ce771ed077ecc17fac1ec4306370b4a249680cc1#unsupported-frameworks) doc section